# Javascript work on desktop but not mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile

I have a code in my website that loads hyperlinks after window have been loaded. It seems to work fine with desktop, but doesn't work at all on mobile devices.

```
function hasClass(e, c) {

if (typeof e == "string") e = document.getElementById(e);
var classes = e.className;
if (!classes) return false;
if (classes == c) return true;
return e.className.search("\\b" + c + "\\b") != -1;};

function Links(){
var theURL, theAnchorText, theTitle;
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var i = 0; i<spans.length; i++){
    if (hasClass(spans[i], 'link')){
        theAnchorText = spans[i].innerHTML;
        theTitle = spans[i].title.toLowerCase().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        switch (theTitle) {
            case 'link1': theURL = 'http://domain.com/example/'; break;

            default: theURL = 'javascript: void(0)';
        }
        spans[i].innerHTML = '<a href="' + theURL + '" class="' + spans[i].className + '">' + theAnchorText + '</a>';
        spans[i].removeAttribute('title');
    }
}}

window.onload = function(){
Links();}
```

Any advice why this isn't working with mobile devices? I have absolutely no coding experience, so it might be something really simple.

Comment: I'm just wondering how this can work on a desktop, since 'affiliateLinks()' function does not exist. Is there a piece of code missing in your post maybe?

Comment: Please also provide the code of `hasClass()`.

Comment: affiliateLinks() was mistake, sorry about that.

Comment: Added hasClass() function